# ES6 modules initializing the wrong order?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

So I have a tree of modules, and two in particular that are behaving oddly. Using Babel 6 + Browserify (babelify).

Module #1 (WindowManager/index.js) exports a named function called `reducer`, as well as a default export.

```
import WindowManager from './component';

import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { reducer as search_palette } from './SearchPalette';

const initialState = {
    // stuff
};

const window_manager = (state = initialState, action) => {
    // stuff

    return state;
};

export const reducer = combineReducers({window_manager, search_palette})

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        // stuff
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(WindowManager)
```

Module #2 (store.js) imports `WindowManager/index.js`'s `reducer` function and tries to use it.

```
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { reducer as WindowManagerReducer } from './WindowManager';

const initialState = {
    // stuff
};

const FetchApplicationsReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    // stuff

    return state;
}

export default createStore(
    combineReducers({
        applications: FetchApplicationsReducer,
        ui: WindowManagerReducer,
    })
)
```

For some reason, store.js is getting executed before `WindowManager/index.js` and thus the exports are not available.

Anyone run into this?

Comment: Hard to say what's going on without more information / a minimal reproduction. Do you have any circular dependencies?

Comment: No circular dependencies between the two modules in question. Isn't the above enough for a reproduction?

Comment: I'm not sure if this matters, but `store.js` does come after `WindowManager/index.js` sequentially in the module map, so if that also defines the execution order, it _should_ work as expected.

Comment: No: it's both too much and not enough. Too much extraneous stuff like redux on one hand, and on the other hand references to modules in the dependency graph that aren't shown. It's also not clone+run-able.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "sequentially in the module map"? Are you talking about which line the code is on in the bundled output?

Comment: The key numbers in Browserify's emitted module map

Comment: I recommend operating on the assumption that that doesn't convey anything meaningful about this problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107364/discussion-between-yaycmyk-and-jmm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much tweaking, modifying the order of `import` statements fixed the issue. It's a complex tree, so hard to represent here in a way that doesn't involving dumping the whole project... but I think ultimately there may be a bug inside Babel's ES6 module system somewhere.

Comment: did you ever work this out? i had a similar problem also using react with server side rendering and webpack